# AppSync to DynamoDB update query mapping error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, vtl

I have the following DynamoDB mapping template, to update an existing DynamoDB item:

```
{
  "version" : "2017-02-28",
  "operation" : "UpdateItem",
  "key" : {
    "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.application.id),
    "tenant": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.identity.claims['http://domain/tenant'])
  },
  "update" : {
    "expression" : "SET #sourceUrl = :sourceUrl, #sourceCredential = :sourceCredential, #instanceSize = :instanceSize, #users = :users",
    "expressionNames" : {
        "#sourceUrl" : "sourceUrl",
        "#sourceCredential" : "sourceCredential",
        "#instanceSize" : "instanceSize",
        "#users" : "users"
    },
    "expressionValues" : {
        ":sourceUrl" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDbJson($ctx.args.application.sourceUrl),
        ":sourceCredential" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDbJson($ctx.args.application.sourceCredential),
        ":instanceSize" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDbJson($ctx.args.application.instanceSize),
        ":users" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDbJson($ctx.args.application.users)
    }
  },
  "condition" : {
    "expression" : "attribute_exists(#id) AND attribute_exists(#tenant)",
    "expressionNames" : {
      "#id" : "id",
      "#tenant" : "tenant"
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
message: "Unable to parse the JSON document: 'Unrecognized token '$util': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')↵ at [Source: (String)"{↵  "version" : "2017-02-28",↵  "operation" : "UpdateItem",↵  "key" : {↵    "id": {"S":"abc-123"},↵    "tenant": {"S":"test"}↵  },↵  "update" : {↵    "expression" : "SET #sourceUrl = :sourceUrl, #sourceCredential = :sourceCredential, #instanceSize = :instanceSize, #users = :users",↵    "expressionNames" : {↵        "#sourceUrl" : "sourceUrl",↵        "#sourceCredential" : "sourceCredential",↵        "#instanceSize" : "instanceSize",↵        "#users" : "users"↵    }"[truncated 400 chars]; line: 17, column: 29]'"
```

I've tried removing parts, and it seems to be related to the expressionValues, but I can't see anything wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you misspelled the `toDynamoDBJson` method

Replace

```
$util.dynamodb.toDynamoDbJson($ctx.args.application.sourceUrl)
```

with

```
$util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.application.sourceUrl)
```

Note the uppercase **B** in `toDynamoDBJson`.

Comment: Ahhh man! I'd have been pulling my hair out for hours on that one! Thank you so much, that fixed it! @Tinou